# InvalidCastException occurs in System.Windows.Form.dll

Tags: .net

There is a webbrowser variable in MainForm.Designer.cs:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;
```

and , I have this piece of code in MainForm.cs:

```
private void OnPageLoadComplete(...){//webbrowser load complete handler
    Thread t = new Thread(SearchDOM);
    t.Start();
}

private void SearchDOM(){
    while(true){
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement u = doc.GetElementById("u");
        HtmlElement p = doc.GetElementById("p");
        if(u != null && p != null){
            u.InnerText = "this is the username";
            u.InnerText = "this is the password";
            //some other code
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception was occurs in:

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
```

The exception info says that this is not an valid conversion.I don't know how this exception occurs.

There is also another case,how to check whether the webbrowser has load the page complete,the real complete.

Comment: HtmlElement only has partial support for usage in a worker thread.  Don't use a worker thread, it should not be necessary.  Do get rid of the while(true) loop.  Web pages use a lot of Javascript today to build the DOM, there is no event that tells you that it is done.  Use a Timer to try every, say, 100 msec.  But you have to keep in mind that web sites protect themselves against bots and insist on user-typed login.  So this code is pretty much not supposed to work at all.  Contact the web site owner, there is usually a webapi available.